# Render ASP MVC Action/View to string in a non-HttpContext environment / SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, render, httpcontext, signalr

I know it is possible to render a MVC Action to string from another controller within the MVC project, but instead I need to invoke the rendering from a class that does not provide a HttpContext.
In fact it is a inherited class from a SignalR.Hub class.

The basic idea is to pass a rendered ActionResult/View string to all clients via SignalR.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You could send an HTTP request to the controller action in question:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string html = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/controller/action");
    // TODO: broadcast the html to all connected clients
}
```

Comment: That's my interim solution, but I hoped there might be a more elegant way to accomplish this.

Comment: No, there isn't. Without an HttpContext you cannot execute controller actions and render views.